# Consistant volume across all audio files

Tags: mp3, replaygain, audio-normalization

I am having a difficult time getting all my audio balanced at the same volume

I have tried different things

1. `normalising` all tracks to the same level

   - doesn't work
2. `mp3gain`

   - doesn't work
3. both if the above, normalising and then mp3gain and also the reverse order

   - doesn't work

With the mp3gain, most tracks end up at a similar volume but there are still tracks that are noticeably quieter.

The only thing I have found that makes all tracks the same volume is using `peak normalization` on `AIMP` audio player

I'm not a fan of AIMP and prefer other audio players.

Is there a sure fire way to achieve a similar result to AIMPs `peak normalization` and ensure that all tracks are played at the same volume?

Comment: Some music players offer track-specific EQ, such as iTunes.  The best solution would be to obtain higher quality versions of the tracks that aren't loud enough.  Are the problematic tracks ones that you've recorded on your own, or have they been mixed/mastered by professionial engineers and released to the public domain?  If the former, details that include hardware/DAW/gain structure etc are necessary.  If the latter, that's a matter of obtaining a higher quality version of that song/track.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I normalize audio using ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: @music2myear - the question may be about video, but the accepted answer is entirely about audio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replaygain vs Normalization](https://superuser.com/questions/1798767/replaygain-vs-normalization)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to having *done* it, but anytime I hear "How do I" in audio/video if it is not a vlc/audacity question it is likely a ffmpeg question.

Someone wanting to do the same, and apparently with some success.
[How can I normalize audio using ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg)

In case you have never heard of ffmpeg or cannot find it on google.
https://ffmpeg.org/ there are windows/linux/mac versions.

If the above does not get you where you need to be, asking specifically ffmpeg related question will probably get you there. it is a massively complex project used for countless things and at the core of man other projects out there, thus it has a huge development and user base, with community forums about everything ffmpeg. https://ffmpeg.org/contact.html#Forums

Audacity can normalize/save, VLC will I *think* only do it while playing.

Links to VLC and Audacity as well, in case you have never heard of them :-)

VLC: https://www.videolan.org/vlc/ https://wiki.videolan.org/VSG:Audio:Normalization/

Audacity: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/normalize.html

Comment: Audacity's normalisation is peak only. That won't work to make levels *feel* the same. VLC's is a compressor, will change the sound perception. You need ffmpeg's loudnorm.

Comment: Yeah I figured ffmpeg was the solution, just tossing the other two in if they were breadcrumbs to something else functional. I do not do a lot of AV work, but when I have hit wall, ffmpeg was the answer. IN fact a great many "converters" out there are someones front end for ffmpeg.  In desktop apps AND web apps. When that many devs put that much eefofrt into things that work, makes no since to reinvent them :)

Comment: Indeed. I am actually a sound engineer - but I'm *not* a DSP expert, I just push the faders & let someone else write the software;) On Mac I have an app called Myriad, which is a brilliant batch processor, though it only comes out of its box for things like 'balancing my entire iTunes library, cos Apple's routines suck' ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin you mentioned `loudnorm` I have seen that there are a number of other normalisation options available and read somewhere else that `peak normalization`  could be the best option.
What makes `loudnorm` the best option in your opinion? Why is it better than the other normalisation options?

Comment: My first comment covers peak. For 'apparent equivalence' it is completely useless. You need a method that measures RMS or LUFS. Nothing else will work. Gene's link to https://superuser.com/a/323127/347380 covers everything you need to know. I can't help with ffmpeg itself because I just don't use command-line solutions to audio or viseo problems, I use dedicated GUI editors.